# monaca android manifest file settings

Tags: android, iframe, local, monaca

Trying to figure out how to add permissions to config.xml file to allow an ifame to point to my local server http://123.456.7.8 but cannot figure it out.
These are the permissions i need to add, these are from a test version built in android studio using webview that work

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

but cannot figure out how to add the same settings to the monaca config.xml file